# Deploy Django app with Docker

Tags: django, deployment, docker

I'm attempting to deploy a Django app via docker, first locally, and then to a cloud server. I could not find an answer to my initial question before I attempt this: if I run *docker-machine create*, I'm guessing this should be run from within my virtualenv, right?

This would then grab all of my specific app dependencies, and begin to build certificates to throw in the container? If not, please explain otherwise..

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are correct.

I will try to help you by my experience, if you wanna deploy django apps via docker.

1. First you need to setup docker machine in your local machine. Please see the
   [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/). By default driver that will be used is `--driver
   virtualbox default`.
2. List what kind of specifics dependencies images of your apps. Ex:
       you need nginx, postgres, uwsgi, or you need to fetch an image then
       modified that image you can use dockerfile ([its the best practice
       for you](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)).
3. I suggested you to use docker-compose. Really its make our project
   pretty easy to manage. You have to define all images that you need
   for your app in docker-compose file [Please read this reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/).

After you finished develop your app then you want to deploy in production server (cloud) you just need to copy all your project then running your docker-compose. All images dependencies will be automatically pulled in the cloud.

As a reference, you can see this project (this is an open source project that I developed.) On that project, I use make file to manage docker-compose command and it make easy to manage.

1. An example of [dockerfile](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/docker/Dockerfile)
2. An example of [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/docker-compose.yml)
3. An example of [Makefile](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/Makefile)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Very detailed and appreciated answer - I'll give this a try and post any obstacles/experiences